# How can I set up port forwarding for GlassFish on Windows Server 2008 and IIS7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, port, port-forwarding, glassfish

I bought a Windows Server 2008 and installed GlassFish, Java, PostgreSQL etc.

Now my website is running on localhost:8080 in the GlassFish server.

How can I set up a port forwarding such that when a request comes to this server via the usual http port 80, this request gets forwarded to 8080. I have IIS7 running as well.

Comment: Could you make your question more clear? From what I gather you want to port forward from port 80 to 8080 when somebody makes a request from your server?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) extension to IIS7. I will be soon setting up a Windows server with GlassFish and am looking into using ARR.

ARR is capable of load balancing and all kinds of other goodies but may be useful as simple reverse proxy, which sounds like what you want.